# 400 bad request for org.springframework after 300+ loop iterations

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

The API request to an external system runs in a **loop** with iterations passing ids to the same url everytime. It is a GET request and the code looks like.

```
super.getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(super.generateJacksonConverter());

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(KeyConstants.API_KEY, "");
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        final String URL = URLConstants.URL + ID + "?param=true";
        LOGGER.info(URL);

        final ResponseEntity<String> result =
            super.getRestTemplate().exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        subObj = new JSONObject(result.getBody());....
```

The code runs well for around 300 iterations and then suddendly starts giving 400 BAD request.
Looking more deep into the exception, it gives 403 Unauthorised for the request.

The error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:564)
```

Comment: Is ID a constant or a variable.

Comment: Its a variable passed in the method parameter.

Comment: Need more information about this ID, where it comes from, how it is validated.

Comment: ID are basically fetched from database and then based on list length, the for loop iterates of it... starts from (1 upto say 1000...) and log validates that ID was a valid value when the URL was formed.

Comment: If you get a 403 response after sending a large amount of requests it could be that the external system has throttling implemented. Maybe you simply send too many requests in a certain timeframe. Or maybe your token for use of the external API expired? Another option could be that you are trying to access a resource with a specific ID that you have no access too (if they authorize on resource level)

Either way, try to find out why the remote system sends a 403.

Comment: If i run a monitor via postman for the same URL for 5000 iteration, it works.

Comment: also, those ids are valid if i try to run it via postman or restart the application.